# Use OR for ISNUMBER / FIND

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the function:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44))*(other stuff)*(other stuff),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44,"no match",2)
```

I need to change the ISNUMBER section to be an OR statement that captures this logic:

```
ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)) OR ISNUMBER(FIND(filter!$A$1,DumpSample!$H$1:$H$44))
```

I have tried:

```
=XLOOKUP(1,BITOR(ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!F1:F44)), ISNUMBER(FIND(filter!A1,DumpSample!H1:H44)))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(D2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)))*(ISNUMBER(FIND(include!$A$1,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)))*(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(FIND(TRANSPOSE(exclude!$A$1:$A$8),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(exclude!$A$1:$A$8)))=0),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44,"no match",2)
```

But the first statement with G2 should be true again the data I am evaluating and it is not interpreting it that way. Did I mess something up in the formatting?

It seems for every data set I evaluate against it is only grabbing the second filter!A1 criteria, not stopping with the first when it is true.

With the first function,

```
=XLOOKUP(1,ISNUMBER(FIND(G2,DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44))*(other stuff)*(other stuff),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44,"no match",2)
```

Sample data:

DumpSample!F1:F44 = Mypath/Info/Data(531), Mypath/OtherInfo/OtherData(532), or similar

G2 = 531, 532 or other numbers

So basically, it is just filtering against the number in the path.

For the second function:

```
ISNUMBER(FIND(filter!$A$1,DumpSample!$H$1:$H$44))*(other stuff)*(other stuff),DumpSample!$F$1:$F$44,"no match",2)
```

Sample data
DumpSample!F1:F44 is same set as above
DumpSample!H1:H44 has text, e.g mm, cm, m etc.

filter!A1 = mm, cm, m etc.

The rows in the dataset DumpSample!F1:F44 will either have a number matching G2 OR will have something populated in DumpSample!H1:H44. So I need the overall XLOOKUP to evaluate whether the G2 number is a match or the filter!A1 text is a match and then continue on with the filtering in the rest of the function.

I just do not know how to structure the OR statement properly.

Comment: Show some sample data and desired output.

Comment: you can also think of `*` as AND and `+` as OR.  Remember 0 is false and every other number is true.

Comment: @Harun24hr see edits